# Can dark energy be converted into energy source?

Tags: energy, dark-energy

Dark energy is an unexplained phenomena. But can it be used as a energy source?

Comment: I want unusual energy

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2006/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43919/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3):

Dark Energy is simply the name given to the unknown force causing the universes expansion to accelerate, it only really has an effect over extremely vast distances so the likely-hood of it being useful to power anything is quite unlikely. However we know so little about the cause of this expansion it is almost impossible to say whether or not it will ever be harnessed by humans.

Answer (score -1):

Well to use it as an energy source in the first place we have to find it in the first place, however, if we were to find it and able to use it, it is theoretically possible(but not confirmed) to use Dark Energy as an energy source. One example is to power our spaceships. Using dark energy, we could warp spacetime around the spaceship so that we could travel to the distant reaches of space faster than light could not by physically moving the spaceship but instead moving the spacetime around us. We also could use Dark energy to power other devices. So yes it is theoretically possible to use dark energy as an Energy Source however before that day comes we have to find it and test the probabilities of us actually harnessing it.

Comment: How would be it according to you

Comment: According to me, I would feel that Dark Energy does have a lot of potential uses by us. So to me I personally feel that yes, dark energy most probably will be harness-able if we understood it enough. (This is my opinion)